Can't modify width of the container throughout the whole project
Can't change width
I'm using Flutter
double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Only height is modifying. But, not the width why? I think the width is fixed somewhere in some file. I searched everywhere. Where I can find it?

Here you are getting all height and width of some widget or screen. If you provide you code and desired changes you want may be I can help you.
